# create order on admin panel

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, addtocart

How i can create one order from simple product if i just have simple product Sku ? 
or may by should i asked  solution for save quote item on Frontend and create order on admin panel .
i guess i should save Sku and qty but for configurable product in quote item table i saw configurable and simple product saved . so can i use simple product to find configurable and create order ?
this is my code

```
    public function indexAction()
{

    $invoice_id=$this->getRequest()->getParam("id");
    $invoice_model=Mage::getModel("wholesale/invoice")->load($invoice_id);
   echo $invoice_id;
    $item_model=Mage::getModel("wholesale/products")->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter("proforma_id",$invoice_id);
    $productidsku =[];
    foreach ($item_model as $item)
    {
        $productidsku[]=['sku'=>$item->getProductSku(),'qty'=>$item->getQty()];
    }
    $websiteId = Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId();
    $store = Mage::app()->getStore();
    $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->setStoreId($store->getId());
   // $quote->setCurrency($order->AdjustmentAmount->currencyID);
    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
        ->setWebsiteId($websiteId)
        ->load($invoice_model->getCustomerId());

    $quote->assignCustomer($customer);
    $quote->setSendCconfirmation(1);
    foreach ($productidsku as $pro)
    {
         echo $pro['sku']."//".$pro['qty']."<br>";
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute("sku",$pro['sku']);
        echo $product->getId();
        $parentIds = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getParentIdsByChild($product->getId());
        var_dump($parentIds);
        $quote->addProduct($product, new Varien_Object(array('qty' =>$pro['qty'])));

    }

    $billingAddress=$customer->getDefaultBillingAddress();
    if(!$billingAddress) {

      //  echo 333;
        $billingAddress = $quote->getBillingAddress()->addData(array(
            'customer_address_id' => '',
            'prefix' => '',
            'firstname' => 'john',
            'middlename' => '',
            'lastname' => 'Deo',
            'suffix' => '',
            'company' => '',
            'street' => array(
                '0' => 'Noida',
                '1' => 'Sector 64'
            ),
            'city' => 'Noida',
            'country_id' => 'IR',
            'region' => 'UP',
            'postcode' => '201301',
            'telephone' => '78676789',
            'fax' => 'gghlhu',
            'vat_id' => '',
            'save_in_address_book' => 1
        ));

    }else{
        $quote->getBillingAddress()->addData($billingAddress->getData());
    }
    $shippingAddress = $customer->getDefaultShippingAddress();
    if(!$shippingAddress){

    $shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress()->addData(array(
        'customer_address_id' => '',
        'prefix' => '',
        'firstname' => 'john',
        'middlename' => '',
        'lastname' => 'Deo',
        'suffix' => '',
        'company' => '',
        'street' => array(
            '0' => 'Noida',
            '1' => 'Sector 64'
        ),
        'city' => 'Noida',
        'country_id' => 'IR',
        'region' => 'UP',
        'postcode' => '201301',
        'telephone' => '78676789',
        'fax' => 'gghlhu',
        'vat_id' => '',
        'save_in_address_book' => 1
    ));
    /*if ($shipprice == 0) {
        $shipmethod = 'freeshipping_freeshipping';
    }
    */
}else{
        $quote->getShippingAddress()->addData($shippingAddress->getData());
    }
    $shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)
        ->collectShippingRates()
        ->setShippingMethod('flatrate_flatrate')
        ->setPaymentMethod('zarinpalweb');
     $quote->setShippingMethod('flatrate_flatrate');
    $quote->getPayment()->importData(array('method' => 'zarinpalweb'));

    try {
        $quote->collectTotals()->save();
    }catch (Exception $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    try {
        // Create Order From Quote
        $service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $quote);
        $service->submitAll();
        $increment_id = $service->getOrder()->getId();
    }
    catch (Exception $ex) {
        echo $ex->getMessage();
    }
    catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }


    $quote = $customer = $service = null;

    return $increment_id;
}
```